# Why is there no XML option for Stack Overflow's open search results?

Tags: feature-request, opensearch

Is there any particular reason why there is no XML (or JSON) option for Stack Overflow's open search results? The current `https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml` Url returns `text/html`:

```
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using the [search in the api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search)?

Comment: We use open search since it's more standardized across websites

Comment: To be honest, this is the first time I've heard about this feature on this site.

Comment: Well, as [Eric Lippert says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899990/215552): "The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature." And, [elsewhere](https://ericlippert.com/2012/07/17/should-c-warn-on-null-dereference/), "The answer is, as usual, that the compiler team does not have to provide a justification for not doing a feature." Now, we're not talking about compilers here, but the idea is the same; it costs money to build features. Why should they build this feature? Please [edit] your feature request with reasons.